# How can I adapt brightness of my Dell P2720D Monitor under settings with a Intel NUC?

Tags: screen, monitor

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Under settings -> info I can see Ubuntu found a "Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)" as onboard graphiccard.

Comment: Can I confirm the question? You want to control the brightness of an *external* monitor via software? If so, no operating system (that I’m aware of) has this ability. Brightness for external monitors can be set using the buttons on that device.

Comment: Yes, it's for my primary external monitor. On Ubuntu on the top right there is such a setting. I can use it to control the brightness of other monitors with other systems.